# Count rows from table from date month and another text variable

Tags: microsoft-excel

I have a table that collects data based on date and area they live.

So for statistics I need to be able to check the date they were added and the area they were in

Example data page:

```
+   Name   +   Age   +   Date Added   +   Area   +
 John       23        21/01/2013       Manchester
 Roger      85        26/01/2013       London
 Sally      47        25/02/2013       London
```

Example stats page

```
+    Area    + Jan 13 + Feb 13 + Mar 13 + Apr 13.....etc
 Manchester      1         0        0        0
 London          1         1        0        0
```

I hope that explains it. 
Apart from `=MONTH()` converting the dd/mm/yyyy to a single month I don't know where to look

Comment: Is using VBa OK as an answer or not? Also, look up pivot tables as this may work great for this!

Answer (score 0):

I think you want to use Pivot Tables in this case.

Unless you want a formula to create that second table? 
In which case it would be a COUNTIFS statement, which would take into account the Date and the Area.